# foreach array with one key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I've got an object with different values .

```
let arr = [{"Personal": "1000"},{"sport": "2100"},{"Industrial": "1200"},{"Commercial": "2300"},
{"Fashion": "1300"},{"Documentary": "2600"}]
```

How can I foreach them and then put them in an object and pick a name for them like this :

```
"photo_type": {
    "Personal": "1000",
    "sport": "2100",
    "Industrial": "1200",
    "Commercial": "2300",
    "Fashion": "1300",
    "Documentary": "2600"
}
```

**I dont want them to be like 0 and 1 and 2.**

Comment: You may want to show us what your have tried or share minimal reproducible example.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create an object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and by spreading the array.

```js
let array = [{ Personal: "1000" }, { sport: "2100" }, { Industrial: "1200" }, { Commercial: "2300" }, { Fashion: "1300" }, { Documentary: "2600" }],
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: **Doh!** Way better than my multi-step operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const arr = [{"Personal": "1000"},{"sport": "2100"},{"Industrial": "1200"},{"Commercial": "2300"},{"Fashion": "1300"},{"Documentary": "2600"}]
let result = {}
arr.forEach(member => {result = {...result, ...member}}
```